# can join to domain, but ldapsearch fails

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I may join Ubuntu 12.04 to Active Directory server (Windows Server 2008 R2) by Centrify DirectControl Express successfully with this command:

```
sudo adjoin beh-domain.com
```

At the same time, this command fails:

```
ldapsearch -x -v -W -h 10.25.25.46
```

The ip belongs to the server. I couldn't figure out why. It fails with this message:

```
ldap_initialize( ldap://10.25.25.46 )
filter: (objectclass=*)
requesting: All userApplication attributes
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 1 Operations error
text: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this ope
 ration a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1

# numResponses: 1
```

If I don't use -x option, It fails with:

```
ldap_initialize( ldap://10.25.25.46 )
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Unknown authentication method (-6)
    additional info: SASL(-4): no mechanism available:
```

My final goal is to authenticate a user with the AD server from inside PHP web services.

Answer (score 0):

By default 2008R2 do not allow anonymous binding, therefore you would need to use an AD account to perform the ldapsearch.

You can either

1. Use simple authentication and define your AD account using -D:

e.g.

ldapsearch -x -D testuser@domain.com -W -v -h

2. Use Centrify provided ldapsearch and bind with user kerberos ticket:

/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ldapsearch -v -h

e.g.

[testmac@centos ~]$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1623196924
Default principal: testmac@SUPPORT.DOMAIN

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
04/15/15 13:23:51  04/15/15 23:23:50  krbtgt/SUPPORT.DOMAIN@SUPPORT.DOMAIN
    renew until 04/22/15 13:23:51

[testmac@centos ~]$ /usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ldapsearch -v -h 192.168.3.21

SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
..

search result
search: 4
result: 0 Success

3. Run as root and use the machine credentials option provided by Centrify ldapsearch:

sudo /usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ldapsearch -m -v -h

e.g.

[root@centos ~]# /usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ldapsearch -m -v -h 192.168.3.21

Using default machine credential cache for authentication!SASL/GSSAPI 
..

search result
search: 4
result: 0 Success